# how to call javascript functions on scroll beyond a particular point

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I am new to JavaScript and tried a simple code (in pure JavaScript) 
I made a code to make an invisible block of text ( `display:none;` ) to be made visible ( `display:block;` ) when the user scrolls past a point, say 300px.
Here is my complete code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
    position: absolute;
}
p{
    margin-top: 300px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    display: none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
onscroll = function() {
  if (scrollTop > 400) {
    getElementById('p').style.cssText ="display:block;";
  } else {
    if {
      getElementById('p').style.cssText ="display:none;";
    }
  }
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if everything is invisible what will you scroll ???

Comment: it should rather have been opacity:0; and opacity:1;

Comment: the code given above is wrong, i want anyone to suggest how to reach the desired result

Comment: @user2906766 Someone has

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  if (window.scrollY > 400) {
    document.getElementById('p').style.cssText ="display:block;";
  } else {

      document.getElementById('p').style.cssText ="display:none;";

  }};
```

i have removed empty if block ,it was without condition
scrollTop is not there in DOM API its scrollY

for best cross browser solution ;use jquery scrollTop function

Comment: I would just use `style.display="none";`

Answer (score 0):

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kSCAx/4/)**

### JQuery

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($("body").scrollTop()>=200)
    {
        $("#p2").css("display", "block");
    }
})
```

### HTML

```
<p id="p1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p id="p2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

### CSS

```
        body {
            position: absolute;
        }
        p
        {
            line-height:90px;
            background-color:yellow;
        }
        p#p2 {
            display: none;
            background-color:orange;
        }
```

Here the 2nd `<p>` element is by default hidden and when `body` scrolls down 200 px it comes in display.